# how to format created date to iso UTC format Sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How can I format this date

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(@Created_x0020_Date,'0;#','')"></xsl:value-of>
```

to something like this UTC format  - "2012-01-13T16:14:21Z"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're looking for the [ddwrt:FormatDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583143%28office.11%29.aspx#officesharepointddwrt_formatdatetime) function:

> FormatDateTime(string szDate, long lcid, string szFormat)

Internally, it wraps standard ASP.Net [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method, so for szFormat parameter you can use either [Standard Data Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) or [Custom Data Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

It seems that [standard sortable format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Sortable) should do for you:

> The "s" standard format specifier represents a custom date and time
>   format string that is defined by the
>   DateTimeFormatInfo.SortableDateTimePattern property. The pattern
>   reflects a defined standard (ISO 8601), and the property is read-only.
>   Therefore, it is always the same, regardless of the culture used or
>   the format provider supplied. The custom format string is
>   "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss".

Thus, your code will look something like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(translate(@Created_x0020_Date,'0;#',''), 1033, 's')" />
```

Then, you can append "Z" to the end of the resulting string (or you can just use custom format).

Comment: Thanks Omlin. `"0211-12-02T14:47:03"`

But this is what i'm getting